# What is the maximum attainable level?

Tags: payday-2

You can level up by doing jobs, which earns you experience. What is the maximum level that can be reached?

The highest I've seen so far ingame is 48.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's 100 (120 Skill-points)

Sources:

[CONFIRMED: Level Cap](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864975632796732608/)

[What will be the max level in the real game?](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864974467808797057/)

[Highest level on payday 2?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130814154902AAeVgvk)

[Whats the Max level achievable now?](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/682607-payday-2/67003880)

Answer (score 3):

According to [the achievements board](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/PAYDAY2/achievements), the current level cap is 100 (cf. *Most Wanted* achievement).

You earn one skill point per level and two additionnal skill points every 10 levels for a total of 120 skill poins.

Answer (score 0):

As of the new infamy update, the new level is 600, put prints like V-100. The infamy level system works like this: Roman Numeral * 100 + Number. **EDIT: Infamy 2.0 brings XV-100.**

Comment: Sorry for late edit.

Answer (score -3):

If you become infamous you can get above level 100. There is a difficulty for level 145 and higher called "overkill 145+" (not the most creative name...)

Comment: This is Payday 2. Not Payday: The Heist. Also there is no infamy in Payday: The Heist as it just happens the level cap is over 100. In fact level 145 is no longer the level cap. Since the release of the Wolf Pack DLC the new level cap is 192, however introducing no new difficulty.