# How are skill points allocated?

Tags: payday-2

Looking at the [Payday 2 skill calculator](http://www.pd2skills.info/), it is stated that a level 100 character will have 120 skill points in total. If I set the skill calculator to my current level it states I have 65 points to spend at level 55.

Since you only get a skill point each time you level, where do the other 20 skill points come from and when do you get them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get 1 skill point per level and every 10 levels, you are awarded with 2 additional skill points, totalling in 120 skill points on level 100.

Answer (score 4):

From [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/128115/15726):

> You earn one skill point per level and two additionnal skill points
>   every 10 levels for a total of 120 skill poins.